# How to boost a Keras based neural network using AdaBoost?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, adaboost, boosting

Assuming I fit the following neural network for a binary classification problem:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(21, input_dim=19, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(80, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(80, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(x2, training_target, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=32, verbose=0,validation_split=0.1, shuffle=True,callbacks=[hist])
```

How would I boost the neural network using AdaBoost? Does keras have any commands for this?

Answer (score 18):

This can be done as follows:
First create a model (for reproducibility make it as a function):

```
def simple_model():                                           
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(25, input_dim=x_train.shape[1], kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],)))
    model.add(Dense(10, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model
```

Then put it inside the sklearn wrapper:

```
ann_estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn= simple_model, epochs=100, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
```

Then and finally boost it:

```
boosted_ann = AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator= ann_estimator)
boosted_ann.fit(rescaledX, y_train.values.ravel())# scale your training data 
boosted_ann.predict(rescaledX_Test)
```

Comment: How would you rescale the data?

Comment: can we pass the keras Data Generator to SkLearn wrapper ?

Answer (score 3):

Keras itself does not implement adaboost. However, Keras models are compatible with scikit-learn, so you probably can use `AdaBoostClassifier` from there: [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html). Use your `model` as the `base_estimator` after you compile it, and `fit` the `AdaBoostClassifier` instance instead of `model`.

This way, however, you will not be able to use the arguments you pass to `fit`, such as number of epochs or batch_size, so the defaults will be used. If the defaults are not good enough, you might need to build your own class that implements the scikit-learn interface on top of your model and passes proper arguments to `fit`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. When I insert: 
`bdt = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=model)`
`bdt.fit(x2, training_target)` where model is my compiled keras network, it gives me the error: *TypeError: Cannot clone object '<keras.models.Sequential object at 0x000000004296B320>' (type <class 'keras.models.Sequential'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.*

Comment: Apparently, by themselves keras classifiers are not scikit-learn compatible. See this article for details on how to make them work together: https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, neural networks are not compatible with the sklearn Adaboost, see https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1752

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.