# Using scikit-learn's MLPClassifier in AdaBoostClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, adaboost

For a binary classification problem I want to use the `MLPClassifier` as the base estimator in the `AdaBoostClassifier`. However, this does not work because `MLPClassifier` does not implement `sample_weight`, which is required for AdaBoostClassifier (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1752)). Before that, I tried using a Keras model and the `KerasClassifier` within `AdaBoostClassifier` but that did also not work as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063676/how-to-boost-a-keras-based-neural-network-using-adaboost) .

A [way](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281522/using-tensorflow-neural-network-with-sklearns-adaboost), which is proposed by User V1nc3nt is to build an own `MLPclassifier` in TensorFlow and take into account the sample_weight.

User V1nc3nt shared large parts of his code but since I have only limited experience with Tensorflow, I am not able to fill in the missing parts. Hence, I was wondering if anyone has found a working solution for building Adaboost ensembles from MLPs or can help me out in completing the solution proposed by V1nc3nt.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the references, which you had mentioned, I have modified `MLPClassifier` to accommodate `sample_weights`.

Try this!

```py
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier

class customMLPClassifer(MLPClassifier):
    def resample_with_replacement(self, X_train, y_train, sample_weight):

        # normalize sample_weights if not already
        sample_weight = sample_weight / sample_weight.sum(dtype=np.float64)

        X_train_resampled = np.zeros((len(X_train), len(X_train[0])), dtype=np.float32)
        y_train_resampled = np.zeros((len(y_train)), dtype=np.int)
        for i in range(len(X_train)):
            # draw a number from 0 to len(X_train)-1
            draw = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(X_train)), p=sample_weight)

            # place the X and y at the drawn number into the resampled X and y
            X_train_resampled[i] = X_train[draw]
            y_train_resampled[i] = y_train[draw]

        return X_train_resampled, y_train_resampled


    def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
        if sample_weight is not None:
            X, y = self.resample_with_replacement(X, y, sample_weight)

        return self._fit(X, y, incremental=(self.warm_start and
                                            hasattr(self, "classes_")))


X,y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
adabooster = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=customMLPClassifer())

adabooster.fit(X,y)
```

Comment: Great, this worked for me! Much better than setting it up from scratch. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @venkatachalam can you explain what is that "draw" number for?

Comment: Its the index sample we compute.